# File downloaded successfully through WGET can't be located

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a zipped file through WGET, the url is **http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/sub/3584243**. When you try to load it into browser, a pop-up wndow appears asking you where to download it into. When I am trying to download it through WGET, the status says download complete, it eve shows the correct file size in diagnostics, but I can't find the file in the folder. What can possibly be wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: From the command line you can clearly read that `wget` tries to download two urls because it handles your directory as another url. Next time try `wget --help` first. Also, resize the screenshot and focus on the important command line output. Nobody cares for all your desktop icons.

Comment: Sorry. Will do it next time onwards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `wget` in a wrong way. Use the `-P` switch to specify a directory to save the download to.

**Wrong:** `wget http://your.url your_directory`

**Correct:** `wget -P your_directory http://your.url`

Also, try adding `--content-disposition` to get the correct file name from urls where the file name itself is not part of the url (like in your example):

`wget  --content-disposition -P your_directory http://your.url`